# How do I get the user claims after I have logged in with IdentityServer 4?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4

I have used this sample to setup IdentityServer4 with angular and WebApi (ASP.NET Core): https://github.com/damienbod/AspNet5IdentityServerAngularImplicitFlow

Everything is working, I can login and use the API and everything, but the problem is that I dont get the user information back after login. I need the subjectId so I can get the specific user. I thought it would be returned with claims or something, but the only thing I see in the cookies is the token.

Comment: I think you should have a look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35306021/3825383

Answer (score 0):

It's in the this.user object

```
private manager = new UserManager(getClientSettings());
  private user: User | null;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private configService: ConfigService) {
    super();

    this.manager.getUser().then(user => {
      this.user = user;
      this._authNavStatusSource.next(this.isAuthenticated());
    });
  }
```

The above is from the authentication serivce in angular