# No storage mechanism for grants specified. Use the 'AddInMemoryStores' extension method to register a development version

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I was using my own database for IdentityServer4 following this example:
[IdentityServer4 register UserService and get users from database in asp.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35304038/identityserver4-register-userservice-and-get-users-from-database-in-asp-net-core?noredirect=1&lq=1)
and seeing this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GkkJ6tqMTC0
but I got

> No storage mechanism for grants specified. Use the 'AddInMemoryStores' extension method to register a development version.

You can see it on this screenshot. 
Any one can help me please?

[image]

Comment: Ensure that you are using the latest version of IdentityServer4 which is 1.0.0. It was published in dec. 22.