# How to request claim types in IdentityServer4?

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35306021/6001456) to implement IdentityServer4. I have problem that in ProfileService in procedure GetProfileDataAsync IEnumerable context.RequestedClaimTypes is empty. Should I change my request in Postman to request certain claim types? What can I do so that context.RequestedClaimTypes contains claim types?

My Postman request looks like this:

```
Post http://localhost:57577/connect/token
Authorization: Basic Z2xvYmFsX2F...
Body (x-www-form-urlencoded):
username:user@gmail.com
password:pass
grant_type:password
scope:my_api
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just like the post you followed, you have to request it in your `scope` . You can add `profile email` to it and then you should get those claims. make sure you add them in the client configuration (config.cs) under `AllowedScopes` as well.

Comment: That almost entirely solved my problem. Name and email are available in context.RequestedClaimTypes, but subject is still not available. I added JwtClaimTypes.Subject to UserClaims. To Scopes I added "my_api", "openid", "profile", "email". In Client, I added AllowedScopes: "my_api", "openid", "profile", "email", "sub". In Postman, scope contains "my_api openid profile email".

Comment: JwtClaimTypes.Subject ("sub") claim will be included in User.Claims in API by default.