# Resource owner password credential grant type not supported

Tags: c#, angular, identityserver4

I'm using `Identity Server 4` in my `Angular 5` application.

I configured Identity Server in this way:

```
  public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
        {
            return new List<Client>
            {
                new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "client",
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword, 
                    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                    RequireClientSecret = false, 

                    AllowedScopes = {
                        "api1"
                    },

                    AllowedCorsOrigins = new List<string>
                    {
                        "http://localhost:4200"
                    } 
                }
            };
        }


    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        var cors = new DefaultCorsPolicyService(_loggerFactory.CreateLogger<DefaultCorsPolicyService>())
        {
            AllowedOrigins = { "http://localhost:4200" }
        };
        services.AddSingleton<ICorsPolicyService>(cors);

        services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
                .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients());
    }
```

And this is my Angular configuration:

```
export const oAuthDevelopmentConfig: AuthConfig = {

    clientId: "client",
    scope: "api1",
    oidc: false,
    issuer: "http://localhost:5000",
    requireHttps: false
}
```

and I use configuration this way:

```
...
    signin(): void {
        this.oAuthService
            .fetchTokenUsingPasswordFlowAndLoadUserProfile(this.model.username, this.model.password)
            .then(() => {
                this.authenticationService.init();
...
```

When I try to access to the server I receive the following error but I cannot understand where the problem is:

```
info: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
      Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint for /connect/token
info: IdentityServer4.Validation.NotSupportedResourceOwnerPasswordValidator[0]
      Resource owner password credential type not supported. Configure an IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator.
fail: IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator[0]
      Resource owner password credential grant type not supported
fail: IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator[0]
      {
        "ClientId": "client",
        "GrantType": "password",
        "Scopes": "api1",
        "UserName": "admin@gmail.com",
        "Raw": {
          "grant_type": "password",
          "client_id": "client",
          "scope": "api1",
          "username": "admin@gmail.com",
          "password": "***REDACTED***"
        }
      }
```

What I miss?

Comment: How did you actually configure IdSrv? (In StartUp)

Comment: Did you provide custom IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator? Without that identity server has no idea how to actually validate if password is correct.

Comment: I updated my post

Comment: AFAIK, you either need to add test users, Identity or a custom user store. At the moment, you haven't configured anything for users

Comment: Like@Evk suggested, add an IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator. It says even literally in the error message "Configure an IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator"

Answer (score 10):

This is an old question, but I did some head banging on the same problem today. 
I discoverd this method: **AddResourceOwnerValidator**. This method may not have existed when this question was asked.

Here is my AddIdentityServer configuration.

```
        services.AddIdentityServer(opt => opt.IssuerUri = issuerUri)
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(IdServer.Configuration.GetApiResources())
            .AddInMemoryClients(IdServer.Configuration.GetClients())
            .AddProfileService<ProfileService>()
            .AddResourceOwnerValidator<ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>()
            ;
```

At the time of the original question, the answer was probably like this, as shown in the question [IdentityServer4 register UserService and get users from database in asp.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35304038/identityserver4-register-userservice-and-get-users-from-database-in-asp-net-core)

```
//Inject the classes we just created
services.AddTransient<IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator, ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>();
services.AddTransient<IProfileService, ProfileService>();
```

Comment: Hey, yes, this really just saved my bacon, thanks for the update. Not sure how they got it to work before without that to be honest lol.