# Trying to add IdentityServer4 as identity authority for a Javascript application with custom user store

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, identityserver4, oidc-client-js

I've followed the [IdentityServer4](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/) documentation to create a basic local implementation using the default test configuration (with in-memory clients and users). At this point IS4 is initialized as follows:

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
    .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
    .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
    .AddTestUsers(Config.GetUsers());
```

I've then [followed the instructions](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/7_javascript_client.html) for creating a simple Javascript application using the [oidc-connect](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js) library. This works fine so now I have a Javascript application which lets a user sign in via my IS4 instance. This JS application is represented within IS4 as a client using implicit flow as per the instructions.

I now want to integrate my IS4 instance with my real users store. Having read a few articles it would seem I need to provide implementations for `IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator` and `IProfileService` as per [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35304038/identityserver4-register-userservice-and-get-users-from-database-in-asp-net-core) and various others.

I've done this, for now just using a dummy user repository which works with a dummy set of in-memory users rather than a real external store. My IS4 initialization now looks like this:

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
    .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
    .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients());

builder.Services.AddTransient<IProfileService, CustomProfileService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator, CustomResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>();
```

Now when I go back and test my Javascript application this is where it gets weird. When trying to sign in I'm taken to my IS4 login screen. I enter the credentials I expect to work but *Invalid username or password* is returned. Debugging I can see that the code never enters my `ValidateAsync` method in `CustomResourceOwnerPasswordValidator`. *However*, by chance I've found that if I enter either **bob** or **alice** as username and password (so, for example, entering **bob** as username *and* password) then I'm authenticated and can return back to my application. This doesn't make any sense. I'm sure it's no coincidence that those are the usernames which are the two default users used by the IdentityServer4 sample in-memory users, but you can see above I'm no longer using in-memory users. In fact, this is still true even when I comment the `GetUsers` method out of `Config.cs`.

I can't explain this, but in any case what I want is to be able to use my user store. So I read a bit further and have seen suggestions that I can only use `IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator` with clients that have `GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword`. However, when I change my Javascript app's client in IS4 to use this grant type, when I try to log in I see an *unauthorized_client* error.

So I'm stuck. I had thought that since I had my setup working with in-memory users then it wouldn't be much work to use a real user store, but clearly there's something I'm missing. Your guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: If that second piece of code is really your IS4 startup, I can't explain why "Bob" and "Alice" work because you haven't wired-up _any_ profile service -- you need to add an `.AddProfileService(CustomProfileService)` call to your `AddIdentityServer` setup sequence. What does your dummy user-store look like? Also, you don't need to register `IProfileService` for injection, IS4 doesn't use it and it isn't useful for user-management when  you're writing your IS4 user interface code.

Comment: Turns out bob and alice were being used as test users in the quick start `AccountController` I was using. A quick search of the codebase for "alice" would have turned this up so I'm looking pretty stupid!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to inject your `ProfileService` as a dependency in your services.

You need something like:

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddProfileService<CustomProfileService>()
            //..... more code
```

And furthermore - your `CustomProfileService` doesn't need to implement `IProfileService` (the method accepts a generic).

The real "magic" happens in the `AccountController` in :

```
/// <summary>
    /// Handle postback from username/password login
    /// </summary>
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginInputModel model)
    {
        // logic
    }
```

There, in the `LoginInputModel` you have the username, password etc. That you need to validate, so at the end there is no real need of the `IProfileService` if you are writing your custom user management.

Comment: Thank you. I was clearly barking up the wrong tree! With your help I now have this working. This also explains why my bob and alice users were working - they were set as test accounts for the quick start `AccountController`.