# Pass request data through identityserver4 login to identity usermanager

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have a angular app that logs in via identityserver4 using dotnet identity.

My identity user has been customised to be multi tenant, I need to know the url of the angular app from within the identity user manager.

Any suggestions would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can use [ProfileService](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/profileservice.html). You have access to `Client` info on the [RequestContext](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/profileservice.html#profiledatarequestcontext) information. I suggest you to read the [Doc](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/profileservice.html) as its best reference.

And if you want to add your own user store, you should do sth like what is done for [TestUsers](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/main/src/IdentityServer4/src/Test/IdentityServerBuilderExtensions.cs#L21):

- Add your custom `UserStore`
- Add your custom `ProfileService`
- Add your custom `ResourceOwnerValidator`
- Add them to `IIdentityServerBuilder` like this:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton(new CustomUserStore(users));
builder.AddProfileService<CustomProfileService>();            builder.AddResourceOwnerValidator<CustomResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>();
```

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35304038/identityserver4-register-userservice-and-get-users-from-database-in-asp-net-core) is an other question regarding custom userstore with all details